# How to display hidden line types properly when printing from AutoCAD?

Tags: polyline-creation, autocad

I want to show the pline type in hidden line type but when I change it I can't show it in printed paper, if I explode it the line are so small that can't show at print, so I want to change the pline to single line, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using AutoCAD. There is no need to explode the polylines to lines in order to see the dashed lines in print. If you have the dashed lines visible properly in the modelspace, you can just try changing the value of `PSLTSCALE` system variable. Try setting its value to 0.5,0.25 etc and refresh(regen) the paperspace.